# Bedeutung von "wegen, um ... willen"

Tags: translation, meaning, phrase

Beim Übersetzen vom Griechischen ins Deutsche bin ich auf ein Problem mit der Übersetzung von `ενεκα` gestoßen. Im Gemoll (Griechisch-Deutsch Wörterbuch) steht, dass diese Präposition normalerweise mit dem Genitiv steht und dass man diese mit *wegen, um ... willen* übersetzen soll.

Meine Frage ist: Was ist mit *wegen, um ... willen* gemeint? Deutsch ist meine zweite Sprache und ich kenne den Ausdruck nicht. Der Duden hilft mir gerade auch nicht.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Es ist nicht ein Ausdruck, sondern es sind zwei Alternativen: *wegen* und *um ... willen*. Also etwa *wegen des Gewitters* oder *um des Friedens willen*.

Comment: Oh, es ist vielleicht zu spät Griechisch zu übersetzen! Jedenfalls, vielen Dank!